# Does the ChildWindow work on MacOS?

Tags: macos, silverlight-5.0, childwindow

Does the ChildWindow work on Mac in an out-of-browser application (or in-browser, for that matter)?  So far, I have not been able to make it work.

Is there a list somewhere of all the Silverlight features that *don't* work on Mac?  That would be useful in evaluating Silverlight for "cross-platform" development.

Comment: Damn it, it looks like Popup is not supported on Mac, either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work (both ChildWindow and Popup). Make sure you disable the popup blocking option in the security settings of Safari. You may need to close and restart Safari as well.